# Crystal Reports database field length

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm running a Crystal Report connecting to a SQL Server 2005 database.
When I use Standard Report Expert and added my SQL Server table and clicked on 'Browse data', the field length seems to be double what is in the database for strings (nvarchars and varchars).  Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried using a different driver?  Perhaps OLEDB?

Comment: I used OLEDB and same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC a field thats nvarchar(2000) for example will hold 2000 characters but it has 4000 bytes reserved since each char requires 2bytes storage. could this be the problem that you're seeing... SQL lists size in characters and crystal lists size in bytes?